# How to make this tree generation faster(doctrine2+extension)?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, tree, doctrine-orm

I am using DoctrineExtensions for managing a nested tree(nested tree behavior). I have to import 10-20K records from a csv file and store them in the database.

I created a service for this task which makes a bunch of new categories(tree nodes), sets the parents of these categories and persists them and in the end I call EntityManager#flush method to save the created categories into the database.

According to my logic, the process should go like this:

1. The extension calculates the data needed for each node(right, left, level etc.)
2. Doctrine makes a query in which it inserts all the data, similarly to this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, parent_id, root, left, ...) VALUES
   (fields of 1st record),
   (fields of 2st record),
   ...
   ```

However, Doctrine inserts each record separately, additionally root, left and right values get updated during the flush causing a huge amount of update queries to be needed.

For inserting 70 categories, I needed ~250 queries, when I wanted to add 500 categories, the program terminated due to memory shortage.

How could I optimize the process? Of course I could write it from scratch, but I'd really love to use this superb extension.

Comment: Is it possible, and did you try to split your import, to call flush before the end. (ie: Load the 20 first, flush (sql queries...), load the 20 next, flush, etc)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not make a difference, and did the same amount of requests.

Comment: Also, be aware than when you `flush()` the entity manager, doctrine will enter transaction mode, do all its requests and then commit.
So even if there's a lot of queries, the performance impact is less than you would think. But if you really need better performance, use raw sql ... :/

Comment: I don't really care about the number of queries as long as it's relatively fast. I would say, for importing 15000 records, the optimal time would be <60s because the process will rarely happen. However, 8200 queries for importing 500 records(it takes 43s) feels really much.

Comment: @DavidFrank post an answer with your solution, then accept it instead of posting the solution inside the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use materialized path tree instead of nested tree. I know, it's not a real solution for this problem, however it works efficiently. If you have a better solution, please post it, and I might accept it as the solution.